# SQL Select rows comparing a datetime field that could be null

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, null

Let's guess we've got the following table:

```
- id (int) 
- active (int)
- active_from (datetime) (NULL)
- active_until (datetime) (NULL)
```

Now, what I want to get is all the **active** records. An **active** record implies:

```
 - active = 1
 - active_from <= current_date (IF IT'S NOT NULL)
 - active_until >= current_date (IF IT'S NOT NULL)
```

I'm looking for a query that applies these 3 requirements in one single query. I'm currently using:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE active = 1 AND active_from <= NOW() AND active_until >= NOW();`

I will only get the behavior I want with rows that don't have `NULL` `active_from` or `active_until`.

Note: I know it would be more appropiate to compare the current date after storing it in a variable (posing it this way because I'm filling it with PHP parameters).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with the rows that have `NULL` values? Exclude them? Include them?

Comment: Include them, since `active_*` columns are setting a datetime range filter. If they are not set, there's no range filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName 
WHERE active = 1 
AND (active_from  < CURDATE() 
OR active_from IS NULL) 
AND (active_until > CURDATE() 
OR active_until IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ifnull in your query (encase active_from and active_until in it):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

So, basically, if the value is null, use another date instead. Which date is up to you and the specific business logic you need (ex: 2100-01-01 or 1900-01-01 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE active = 1 
AND (active_from  < CURDATE() 
AND active_from IS NOT NULL) 
AND (active_until > CURDATE() 
AND active_until IS NOT NULL)